# What is weird about wrapping setjmp and longjmp?

Tags: c, gcc, exception

I am using setjmp and longjmp for the first time, and I ran across an issue that comes about when I wrap setjmp and longjmp. I boiled the code down to the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf jb;

int mywrap_save()
{
  int i = setjmp(jb);
  return i;
}

int mywrap_call()
{
  longjmp(jb, 1);
  printf("this shouldn't appear\n");
}

void example_wrap()
{
  if (mywrap_save() == 0){
    printf("wrap: try block\n");
    mywrap_call();
  } else {
    printf("wrap: catch block\n");
  }
}

void example_non_wrap()
{
  if (setjmp(jb) == 0){
    printf("non_wrap: try block\n");
    longjmp(jb, 1);
  }  else {
    printf("non_wrap: catch block\n");
  }
}

int main()
{
  example_wrap();
  example_non_wrap();
}
```

Initially I thought example_wrap() and example_non_wrap() would behave the same. However, the result of running the program (GCC 4.4, Linux):

```
wrap: try block
non_wrap: try block
non_wrap: catch block
```

If I trace the program in gdb, I see that even though mywrap_save() returns 1, the else branch after returning is oddly ignored.  Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: If you're trying to build an exception-handling-like system in C: just don't.  It'll be cute, but without RAII or garbage collection, you'll be asking for resource leaks.  Single-entry/single-exit with `goto` is a better error-handling technique in C.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, that is not my intention. That said, you can have garbage collection in C, using a library that wraps malloc/free. For instance, look up Boehm GC.

Comment: Even with a GC, there are more resources than just memory (file handles, mutexes, ...).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 The longjmp() routines may not be called after the routine which called
 the setjmp() routines returns.
```

In other words, you are screwing up your stack.

You might take a look at the assembly to see if you can piece together what's really happening.

Comment: So you'll need to use a macro for `mywrap_save()`.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly correct. I am dumb for not realizing it earlier. The code didn't crash, and hence I didn't catch it. Serves me right for using setjmp and longjmp :)

Answer (score 1):

`setjmp()` will save the current call stack and mark a point. When the call stack grows, no matter how far from the marked point, you can use `longjmp()` to go to the marked point, like you never left the point.

In your code, when returning from `mywrap_save()`, the marked point was no longer valid, the stack space around the point was dirty, hence you cannot go back to a dirty point.